# in array error on user list checkbox

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to figure out the error on my view page for my check box **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)**

I am not to sure on what the bug is and or how to fix it.

```
foreach ($user->result() as $row) {

echo '<tbody>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td class="text-center">' . if (in_array($row->user_id, $selected)) {  .'</td>';
echo '<td class="text-center">' . form_checkbox(array('name' => 'selected[]', 'value' => $row->user_id, 'checked' => 'checked')) .'</td>';
echo } else {;
echo '<td class="text-center">' . form_checkbox(array('name' => 'selected[]', 'value' => $row->user_id)) .'</td>';
echo };
echo '<td class="text-center">' . $row->user_id  .'</td>';
echo '<td class="text-center" style="font-weight: bolder;">' . $row->username  .'</td>';
echo '<td class="text-center">' . ($row->status ? $this->lang->line('text_enabled') : $this->lang->line('text_disabled'))  .'</td>';
echo '<td class="text-center">' . $row->date_added  .'</td>';
echo '<td class="text-center">' . anchor("admin/users/edit/" . $row->user_id, '<div class="btn btn-primary text-right" role="button"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
 Edit</div>')  .'</td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '</tbody>';

}
```

Comment: I have that here echo } else {; 5 line down

Comment: You can't combine `if()` with the concatenation operation `.`.

Comment: Why should your if be inside a td?

Comment: Because its a big cms user system making. Easier to manage this way. And when work with other functions on controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using `if()` inside a concatenation, you need to refactor:

```
foreach ($user->result() as $row) 
{
    echo '<tbody>';
        echo '<tr>';

        if (in_array($row->user_id, $selected)) 
        {
            echo '<td class="text-center">' . form_checkbox(array('name' => 'selected[]', 'value' => $row->user_id, 'checked' => 'checked')) .'</td>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<td class="text-center">' . form_checkbox(array('name' => 'selected[]', 'value' => $row->user_id)) .'</td>';
        }

        echo '<td class="text-center">' . $row->user_id  .'</td>';
        echo '<td class="text-center" style="font-weight: bolder;">' . $row->username  .'</td>';
        echo '<td class="text-center">' . ($row->status ? $this->lang->line('text_enabled') : $this->lang->line('text_disabled'))  .'</td>';
        echo '<td class="text-center">' . $row->date_added  .'</td>';
        echo '<td class="text-center">' . anchor("admin/users/edit/" . $row->user_id, '<div class="btn btn-primary text-right" role="button"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit</div>')  .'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    echo '</tbody>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More or less you should better follow this approach. You cant concatenate if statements in echo/print.

```
foreach ($user->result() as $row) {
$out = '<tbody>';
$out .= '<tr>';
$out .= '<td class="text-center">';
$out .='</td>';
if (in_array($row->user_id, $selected)) {      
  $out .= '<td class="text-center">' . form_checkbox(array('name' => 'selected[]', 'value' => $row->user_id, 'checked' => 'checked')) .'</td>';
} 
else {
  $out .= '<td class="text-center">' . form_checkbox(array('name' => 'selected[]', 'value' => $row->user_id)) .'</td>';
}
$out .= '<td class="text-center">' . $row->user_id  .'</td>';
$out .= '<td class="text-center" style="font-weight: bolder;">' . $row->username  .'</td>';
$out .= '<td class="text-center">' . ($row->status ? $this->lang->line('text_enabled') : $this->lang->line('text_disabled'))  .'</td>';
$out .= '<td class="text-center">' . $row->date_added  .'</td>';
$out .= '<td class="text-center">' . anchor("admin/users/edit/" . $row->user_id, '<div class="btn btn-primary text-right" role="button"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
 Edit</div>')  .'</td>';
$out .= '</tr>';
$out .= '</tbody>';
}

echo $out;
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for spotting. I have kep $out .='</td>'; in the if condition which should be out side of that.